# Extra space when using tabular and overlay

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I am trying to make a simple animation to change rows of a tabular from normal text to bold text. I tried to do it with \only and \alt, but I end up getting an extra space in the beginning of the row.

My question is: Is there a way to apply overlay on the entire row and not have the extra space?

So far I have the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}
  \hline
  Foo & Bar\\
  \hline
  \alt<2>{
    \textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Bar}\\
  }{
    Foo & Bar\\
  }
  Foo & Bar\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

And the result:
[image: Tabular with extra space (time 1)]
[image: Tabular with extra space (time 2)]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It should be `}{%`. You are inserting some spurious space in your seventh line of code. Please make your example compilable. This makes it easier for us to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You introduced some spurious space by adding new lines in your code. Just get rid of the new lines or use `%` at its end. The very problem here was your seventh line of code.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        Foo & Bar\\
        \midrule
        \alt<2>{\textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Bar}
        }{% % you had an extra space here introduced by the new line of code. Write it on one line or add an % at the end of it. 
        Foo & Bar}\\
        Foo & Bar\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Apart from this, I would recommend to use `\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{.585cm}}}`. Like this, your 'animation' will result better...

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{.585cm}}}\toprule
        Foo & Bar\\\midrule
        \alt<2>{\textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Bar}}{Foo & Bar}\\
        Foo & Bar\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{l}}\toprule
        Foo & Bar\\\midrule
        \alt<2>{\textbf{Foo} & \textbf{Bar}}{Foo & Bar}\\
        Foo & Bar\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the recommendation!

Comment: @Unwise You are very welcome.